# Excel VBA parse column, extract all substrings

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to parse a column that contains data in the following format in each cell -

pull: test1

or

pull: test2|pull: test3|.....

or

other: blah...

I only want a grab each "Pull: test" and place 1 in each row in a new worksheet like below, and ignore any parts of the cell that don't begin with "pull: " -

pull: test1

pull: test2

pull: test3

...

What I have so far just pulls the entire column and pastes into the same spreadsheet, I'm not sure how to separate the items in each cell into their own rows. I also can't get it to pull to a different worksheet correctly either (commented out my attempt)

```
Sub InStrDemo()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer, icount As Integer

'Sheets.Add.Name = "TEST"

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If InStr(1, LCase(Range("E" & i)), "pull:") <> 0 Then
        icount = icount + 1
        'Sheets("TEST").Range("A" & icount & ":E" & icount) = Worksheets("SearchResults").Range("A" & i & ":E" & i).Value
        Range("L" & icount) = Range("E" & i).Value
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want a new worksheet for each row of data or do you want the content to be split on pipes (`|`) and then put in a single column in the same new sheet?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad split on the pipes and 1 on each row in the same column of a new sheet

Comment: If you have Excel 2010 or later, just use `Power Query`.  The `Split Column` dialog allows for splitting on `|` and splitting into rows.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, written on mobile.

```
Option Explicit

Sub testDemo()

Dim sourceSheet as worksheet
Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet ' would be more reliable to qualify the workbook and worksheet by name'

Dim outputSheet as worksheet
Set outputSheet = thisworkbook.worksheets.add

Dim lastRow As Long

lastrow = sourceSheet.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

' I assume column E needs to be parsed'
Dim arrayOfValues() as variant
arrayOfValues = sourceSheet.range("E1:E" & lastRow)

Dim rowIndex as long
Dim columnIndex as long
Dim splitString() as string
Dim cumulativeOffset as long

Dim toJoin(0 to 1) as string
toJoin(0) = "pull: test" ' Might speed up string concatenation below'

Dim outputArray() as string

With outputsheet.range("A1") ' The first row you want to start stacking from'

For rowIndex = 1 to lastRow

' Single dimensional, 0-based array'
splitString = VBA.strings.split(vba.strings.lcase$(arrayOfValues(rowIndex,1)), "pull: test",-1, vbbinarycompare)

Redim outputArray(1 to (ubound(splitString)+1), 1 to 1)

For columnIndex = lbound(splitString) to ubound(splitString)
toJoin(1) = splitString(columnIndex)

Outputarray(columnIndex+1,1) = VBA.strings.join(toJoin, vbnullstring)

Next columnIndex

'Instead of splitting upon a delimiter, then prepending the delimiter to each array element (as is done above), you could repeatedly call instr(), use mid$() to extract the sub-string, then increase the argument passed to the "Start" parameter in instr() (effectively moving from start to end of the string) -- until instr() returns 0. Then move on to the next string in the outer loop.'

.offset(cumulativeOffset,0).resize(Ubound(outputArray, 1), 1).value2 = outputArray

cumulativeOffset = cumulativeOffset + ubound(splitString)

Next rowIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: When I run it on my data (added the End With before End Sub), it seems to just copy the entire cell to the same cell A1 of the new sheet (overriding what was previously there), and it also pulls the entire cell contents (doesn't split on the '|' ). Also, I forgot to mention some cells don't even have "Pull: .." in this case, I don't want to pull anything from the cell